# httpUrlCon.getInputStream() causing IOException while calling Restful API

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I called Restful Web Service using HttpURLConnection.Below is the summary of my code:

---

### Rest layer

```
@Path("/ResourceName")
@Scope("request")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class AlertResource {
     @POST
     @Path("/methodName")
     @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
     public Response methodName(
          @@HeaderParam(value = "xxxx") String param1){
      .....
     }
```

---

### action layer

```
public static String callRestfulApp(String urlString, String methodType, 
                      Map<String,   String> parameter) throws Exception{

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    StringBuilder responseText = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlCon = null;
    try {
        URL url;            
        StringBuilder urlData = new StringBuilder();
        urlData.append(urlString);
        url = new URL(urlData.toString());
        httpUrlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpUrlCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlCon.setRequestMethod(methodType);

        if (parameter != null) {
            // Set the parameters
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : parameter.entrySet()) {
                httpUrlCon.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
            }
        }           

        inputStream = httpUrlCon.getInputStream();
        .....
```

I called this using the following line,

```
 parameters.put("xxxx",
          gson.toJson(someBean));

 respons = CommonWebUtils.callRestfulApp(prop.getPropertyValue("RestURI")                     + "ResourceName/methodName",
   "POST", parameters);
```

The problem with above code is , my "someBean" contain huge data,so becuase of this;httpUrlCon.getInputStream() is causeing IOException.If i am passing a less data,then its working fine.I have tried with dirrerent parameter passing technique(query,matrix),but non of those help me.So,how to pass a huge data?

Exception trace:

```
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8091/Restful/ResourceName/methodName
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
        at org.razorsight.alert.web.common.CommonWebUtils.callRestfulApp1(CommonWebUtils.java:149)
        at org.razorsight.alert.web.action.KpiAction.addKpiRule(KpiAction.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
```

Comment: How huge is "huge"?  Please include the details of the `IOException`.

Comment: The URL in the exception `http://localhost:8091/Restful/AlertResource/addKPICriteriaRule` has nothing to do with your Resource, which maps to `/ResourceName/methodName`. Please include your *real* code.

Comment: addKPICriteriaRule is the real method name wich replaceed with "methodName".I modified the exception trace.While searching,i found that may be the server's headerBuffer size me be less.So,i just increased,but it's also not helped me.

Comment: Are you able to open the URL from a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem and its soluation.

I am using `HeaderParam` for passing my parameters to web service.Every server has a configuration of max.size of header that it support.I am using Tomcat 6.So,by `default it suuport max of 8KB`.

But,in my case;the total size of parametes cross 8KB.So,its not able to get the inputstream of the web service method.In order to resolved this provlem,i just modify the default httpheader size it support in `server.xml` of Tomcat using `maxHttpHeaderSize`
property.

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8091" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="15360"/>
```